# Unable to use model class method in home Controller

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, layout, asp.net-mvc-5

HomeController

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Login l)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (l.CheckUser(l.UserName, l.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Home/Home");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Invalid User");
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**Model class (Login)**

```
 namespace sampleprojectone.Models
 {
    public class Login
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Username must not be empty")]
        [Display(Name ="Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password must not be empty")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool CheckUser(string username,string password)
           {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ToString());
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_checklogin", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                bool b = Convert.ToBoolean (cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return b;
           }
     }
 }
```

**Error**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Login' does not contain a definition for 'CheckUser' and no accessible extension method 'CheckUser' accepting a first argument of type 'Login' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    sampleprojectone    G:\King\Projects\sampleprojectone\sampleprojectone\Controllers\HomeController.cs    35  Active

Comment: I'm uncertain, but I think what it might be that you have not referenced your Login class properly yet. Try to have your Login functions named differently than your login class...

`public ActionResult Login()` --> `public ActionResult LoginAction()`
`public ActionResult Login(Login l)` --> public ActionResult LoginWithCreds('Login l')

And try again. If your Login model can not be found, it might be that you have not referenced it properly

Comment: Is it possible that you have a Login controller and as such you need to fully qualify the Login object in your Login method? public ActionResult Login(sampleprojectone.Models.Login l)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used namespace `using sampleprojectone.Models;` in HomeController. Now it is solved thank you cornelis and rob.